# Is there a way to edit a question or answer for a typographic reason and not have the thread placed at the top?

Tags: discussion

I wanna be able to indulge my OCD and "fix" some posts (questions or answers) without the presumption that there is something *"new"* that deserves attention.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid that it is impossible as for now. This question was already answered [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23241/is-there-a-way-to-edit-a-question-without-bumping-it-to-the-front-page). Maybe in the future, we will have a way of doing that.

Comment: grumble, grumble..

Comment: all it takes is a **Minor Edit** check box that defaults as unchecked and another data/time attribute that is the data/time of the most recent **non-Minor Edit** and sort according to that. every edit would be listed in the OP's *Recent Inbox Messages* in case a troll (with sufficient rep) decides to fuck up answers and leave them unnoticed by everyone else.  maybe the admins will sort by most recent edit without regard to *Minor Edit* status to keep a lid on trolls abusing this.  it's not a hard thing to do.

Comment: i meant to write "date/time".  dunno how that became "data/time".